# symbol xmlOutputBufferGetSize, version LIBXML2_2.9.0 not defined in file libxml2.so.2 with link time reference

Tags: apache-2.4, postgresql, php5, tomcat6

I've installed Apache2 and PHP5 via apt-get on Ubuntu 14 (amd64), Tomcat 6, and Postgres 8.4. I get this error message on an attempted restart:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: symbol xmlOutputBufferGetSize, version LIBXML2_2.9.0 not defined in file libxml2.so.2 with link time reference
```

I've removed/purged and reinstalled apache, php, and libapache2-mod-php5 to no avail.

Any thoughts on getting this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that the copy of Postgres I had installed had it's own copy of libxml2.so.2 under `/opt/PostgreSQL/8.4/lib` (ran a quick `ldd /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so`), renaming it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you got the `libapache2-mod-php5` package from has given you a dodgy build.  It doesn't properly declare its package dependencies (or else you `--force`d the package to install, over dpkg's protests).

Find packages that are built for your particular OS version, and use those instead.